# Build error tsc.exe exited with code 2

Tags: node.js, angular

After including node_modules I am getting the error **tsc.exe exited with code 2**
How can I solve this error?

My tscongfig.json is:-

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Like, what is your environment, what IDE, your `tsconfig` file, anything else besides that small error message?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the above issue by changing the **Microsoft.TypeScript.targets** file, I made changes as:-

```
 <TypeScriptCompileBlocked Condition="'$(TypeScriptCompileBlocked)' == ''">true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

by default it was true.
After changing this it is building fine.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what this setting actually does?